# After staining a deck how long until rain is no longer a concern?

Tags: wood, deck, staining

I want to stain my deck with an oil based stain it is to be hot and sunny all day today 85 for a high and has been dry for last 3 days tomorrow's forecast say 70% chance of rain should I do this or put off again. I've had my stain since Memorial Day and we haven't had a dry stretch of more than 2 days in which we needed time for the deck to dry to even consider doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

Most oil-based deck stains need **at least** 24 hours of dry time. High humidity and/or low temperatures will increase that time, so will over-applying the stain. I would **not** apply it unless I was fairly confident that I had at least 48 hours with no rain. Better to wait.

Answer (score 0):

If conditions are hot and dry, my experience is 24 hours is plenty.  As long as it is dry to the touch you should be ok.  A quick note on the stain itself.  Two years ago I discovered Behr Deckover.  This product is more expensive than traditional stains and goes on thick.  However, after two years not a crack or blemish.  Looks like it was just applied.  The mfgr claims crack free for 11 years.  Well worth the trip.